# How to remove the link if value is 0 using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

awesome worked fine for me.. due to security I am editing my code..

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

Replace

```
<%=Html.ActionLink(e.ExceptionTypeName, "VirtualScrollingDataRequested", Model.exceptionCategory.GetControllerName(), new { C_EXCPT_TYPE = e.ExceptionTypeID, GUI_SPEC_STAT_DSPL = 2, C_EXCPT_CATG = Model.exceptionCategory.Id, @ASSET_CLASS = string.Empty, @INST_MNEM = string.Empty, @_lock = "ALL" }, new { @title = e.BuildGridTitle(2, e.ExceptionTypeName) })%>
```

with

```
<%=e.workedexceptions == 0 ? e.ExceptionTypeName : Html.ActionLink(e.ExceptionTypeName, "VirtualScrollingDataRequested", Model.exceptionCategory.GetControllerName(), new { C_EXCPT_TYPE = e.ExceptionTypeID, GUI_SPEC_STAT_DSPL = 2, C_EXCPT_CATG = Model.exceptionCategory.Id, @ASSET_CLASS = string.Empty, @INST_MNEM = string.Empty, @_lock = "ALL" }, new { @title = e.BuildGridTitle(2, e.ExceptionTypeName) })  %>
```

Comment: thanks for your response.. if(e.WorkedException==0) Still I need to show the ExceptionTypeName.. I can not do Continue; that means its not dispalying 0 exceptions